# unable to import com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableDoubleProperty;

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: 
http://jperedadnr.blogspot.sg/2012/09/a-javafx-weekly-scheduler.html

however, IntelliJ is throwing an error here:[image]

Comment: It's always a bad idea to use non-public API, as they may be removed in future releases. These are non-public API classes. In JavaFX 8, there are classes in the public API in the [javafx.css package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/package-summary.html) that look like they may be drop-in replacements. I would recommend trying those in the place of the ones in the tutorial.

Comment: As @James_D suggests, using non public API has its risks... This tutorial was done in 2012 (JavaFX 2), and the `DoubleSlider` control developed at that time doen't work with JavaFX 8. You could try to update it, or you could just replace it now using the `RangeSlider` control from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

Comment: @JoséPereda, Thank you for the suggestion. How do I download that and use it in scene builder?

Comment: I've downloaded the file given on the website you linked to me, however, the folder doesn't have a rangeSlider component...am I overlooking something? your help is much appreciated. thanks a ton

Comment: If you have downloaded this [link](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.40.9.zip), then the jar you need is this: `controlsfx-8.40.9.jar`. It contains `org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider`. You can add this jar to [Scene Builder 8.0](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/), and then drag the control to your scene from the Custom pane. It you want I can add this as a proper answer, a little bit more detailed.

Comment: @JoséPereda got it! Thanks a bunch! I realized I had a very old version of Scene Builder.